# SQL Pivot all columns and rows to single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've searched all over Stack Overflow and the web for an example of what I need to do and just can't seem to figure out how to apply pivoting to accomplish what I need done.  Maybe using Pivot is simply not the right answer, but it just seems like my lack of understanding might be getting in the way.  I have a table whose data looks like this:

```
year    property type   market total    taxable total   parcel count
----    -------------   ------------    -------------   ------------
2012    Real            23453           34563           123
2012    Personal        53434           65432           321
2013    Real            24565           23546           345
2013    Personal        64453           45636           342
2014    Real            76586           78645           876
2014    Personal        56775           67556           897
```

I need to turn it into a result showing all the values as a single row per year like so:

```
year real market real taxable real count pers market pers taxable pers count
---- ----------- ------------ ---------- ----------- ------------ ----------
2012 23453       34563        123        53434       65432        321
2013 24565       23546        345        64453       45636        342
2014 76586       78645        876        56775       67556        897
```

All of the pivot table examples I look at though show the column names as actual values from a column in the source data, which doesn't really seem to be the case for me.  And I am stuck with not being able to dynamically construct SQL.  By the way, the "property type" values are a known set, so I know exactly the number of columns my output will need.

Is doing this possible in SQL in a simple way?  It just seems like it should be...

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what DBMS you are using, but I believe my query should work for you(I'm using SQL Server).

### My Version of Your Table

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE ([year] INT,[Property Type] VARCHAR(20),[Market Total] INT,[Taxable Total] INT,[Parcel Count] INT);
INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  (2012,'Real',23453,34563,123),
        (2012,'Personal',53434,65432,321),
        (2013,'Real',24565,23546,345),
        (2013,'Personal',64453,45636,342),
        (2014,'Real',76586,78645,876),
        (2014,'Personal',56775,67556,897);
```

### Actual Query

```
SELECT  [year],
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Property Type] = 'Real' THEN [Market Total]  END) AS [Real Market],
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Property Type] = 'Real' THEN [Taxable Total] END) AS [Real Taxable],
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Property Type] = 'Real' THEN [Parcel Count]  END) AS [Real Count],

        MAX(CASE WHEN [Property Type] = 'Personal' THEN [Market Total]  END) AS [Personal Market],
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Property Type] = 'Personal' THEN [Taxable Total] END) AS [Personal Taxable],
        MAX(CASE WHEN [Property Type] = 'Personal' THEN [Parcel Count]  END) AS [Personal Count]
FROM @yourTable
GROUP BY [year]
```

Comment: I voted this answer as the most helpful because it presented the most straight-forward solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your result with INNER JOIN query:

Here is MySQL syntax:

```
SELECT t1x.`year`, `real market`, `real taxable`, `real count`,
       `pers market`, `pers taxable`, `pers count`
FROM (SELECT `year`, `market total` AS `real market`, 
         `taxable total` AS `real taxable`, `parcel count` AS `real count`
     FROM t1
     WHERE `property type` = 'Real') t1x
INNER JOIN (SELECT `year`, `market total` AS `pers market`, 
            `taxable total` AS `pers taxable`, `parcel count` AS `pers count`
            FROM t1
            WHERE `property type` = 'Personal') t1y
ON t1x.`year` = t1y.`year`
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8309/1) so you can see how it's work.

Basically you select values from your table (I call it **t1**) into two temporary table **t1x** and **t1y**. Into **t1x** table you select rows form **t1** where **property type** column value is **Real** and into **t1y** where that value is **Personal**. And that Join that two table on **year** column...

SQL Server syntax is pretty much the same the only difference is in that how they handle two words column in MySQL we use back quote (`) and in SQL Server we use brackets like this [];

Here how that syntax look like:

```
SELECT t1x.[year], [real market], [real taxable], [real count],
       [pers market], [pers taxable], [pers count]
FROM (SELECT [year], [market total] AS [real market], 
             [taxable total] AS [real taxable], [parcel count] AS [real count]
     FROM t3
     WHERE [property type] = 'Real')AS t1x
INNER JOIN (SELECT [year], [market total] AS [pers market], 
            [taxable total] AS [pers taxable], [parcel count] AS [pers count]
            FROM t1
            WHERE [property type] = 'Personal') t1y
ON t1x.[year] = t1y.[year]
```

If you use any other database than at least you have idea how to deal with this problem...

GL!

Answer (score 0):

Have the same type of problem often with the data I need to report on, I have used both options and look at performance issue to help me choose what option I would use on a given report.  Often I will push the smallest result data to a temp table and then do the final manipulation for reporting.  This keeps the I/O loads down.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SAMPLEDATA') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SAMPLEDATA; 
CREATE TABLE #SAMPLEDATA
(
    [Year] INT,
    [Property Type] VARCHAR(50),
    [Market] DECIMAL(18,2),
    [Taxable] DECIMAL(18,2),
    [Parcel] INT
)


INSERT INTO #SAMPLEDATA([Year],[Property Type],[Market],[Taxable],[Parcel]) VALUES
    (2012,'Real',23453,34563,123),
    (2012,'Personal',53434,65432,321),
    (2013,'Real',24565,23546,345),
    (2013,'Personal',64453,45636,342),
    (2014,'Real',76586,78645,876),
    (2014,'Personal',56775,67556,897)

-- OPTION 1 (LINKING MULTIPLE PIVIOTS) -- DOWNSIDE -- HITTING THE DATA NUMBEROUS TIMES HIGH I/O

SELECT 
    L.[Year],
    D1.[real market],
    D2.[real taxable],
    D3.[real count],
    D1.[pers market],
    D2.[pers taxable],
    D3.[pers count]
FROM
    (SELECT [YEAR] FROM #SAMPLEDATA GROUP BY [YEAR]) AS L
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [Year],[Real] AS [real market],[Personal] AS [pers market] FROM (SELECT [Year],[Property Type],[Market] FROM #SAMPLEDATA) AS P1 PIVOT (SUM([Market]) FOR [Property Type] IN ([Real],[Personal])) AS DATA1) AS D1
        ON L.[Year] = D1.[Year]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [Year],[Real] AS [real taxable],[Personal] AS [pers taxable] FROM (SELECT [Year],[Property Type],[Taxable] FROM #SAMPLEDATA) AS P2 PIVOT (SUM([Taxable]) FOR [Property Type] IN ([Real],[Personal])) AS DATA2) AS D2
        ON L.[Year] = D2.[Year]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [Year],[Real] AS [real count],[Personal] AS [pers count] FROM (SELECT [Year],[Property Type],[Parcel] FROM #SAMPLEDATA) AS P3 PIVOT (SUM([Parcel]) FOR [Property Type] IN ([Real],[Personal])) AS DATA3) AS D3
        ON L.[Year] = D3.[Year]

-- OPTION 2 (CASE SUMS)
    SELECT 
    [Year],
    SUM (CASE WHEN [Property Type] = 'Real' THEN [Market] ELSE 0 END) AS [real market],
    SUM (CASE WHEN [Property Type] = 'Real' THEN [Taxable] ELSE 0 END) AS [real taxable],
    SUM (CASE WHEN [Property Type] = 'Real' THEN [Parcel] ELSE 0 END) AS [real count],
    SUM (CASE WHEN [Property Type] = 'Personal' THEN [Market] ELSE 0 END) AS [pers market],
    SUM (CASE WHEN [Property Type] = 'Personal' THEN [Taxable] ELSE 0 END) AS [pers taxable],
    SUM (CASE WHEN [Property Type] = 'Personal' THEN [Parcel] ELSE 0 END) AS [pers count]
    FROM 
    #SAMPLEDATA
GROUP BY
    [Year]
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error and looking at other examples, I finally came up with a method that uses the PIVOT operation.  The reason I wanted to use pivot as opposed to the above solutions was because the **real** data I have to query has over 20 "property types" and 4 values per "property type", which makes solving the problem a bit of a monster, but...here's the pivot solution I was able to come up with:

```
with sample_data([year], [property_type], [market_total], [taxable_total], [parcel_count])
as
(
          select 2012, 'Real', 23453, 34563, 123
    union select 2012, 'Personal', 53434, 65432, 321
    union select 2013, 'Real', 24565, 23546, 345
    union select 2013, 'Personal', 64453, 45636, 342
    union select 2014, 'Real', 76586, 78645, 876
    union select 2014, 'Personal', 56775, 67556, 897
),
categorized_data ([year], [column_name], [column_value])
as
(
    select [year], [property_type] + '_market_total', [market_total] from sample_data
    union select [year], [property_type] + '_taxable_total', [taxable_total] from sample_data
    union select [year], [property_type] + '_parcel_count', [parcel_count] from sample_data
)
select * from categorized_data
pivot
(
    max(column_value) for column_name in 
    (
        [Real_market_total], 
        [Real_taxable_total], 
        [Real_parcel_count], 
        [Personal_market_total], 
        [Personal_taxable_total], 
        [Personal_parcel_count]
    )
) as pvt
```

Hopefully, this will help someone else who was as stumped as I was at first.